# cannot create temp dir for user data dir

Tags: selenium

### Chrome browser not launching on remote machine, getting below error

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4) on port 30753
> error   16-Sep-2016 00:13:14    Only local connections are allowed.
> error   16-Sep-2016 00:13:16    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir

**Solutions tried:**

- 1->downgrading chrome version 2-> uninstall n install again
  3->removing chrome profile from user profile

but no luck

Can somone please provide help on this?

here is driver initialization code

```
public void initDriver() {

if (CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("Mozilla")) {
    e_driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(e_driver);
    eventListene = new WebEventListen();
    driver.register(eventListene);
} else if (CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("IE")) {
    e_driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(e_driver);
    eventListene = new WebEventListen();
    driver.register(eventListene);
} else if (CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("Chrome")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.CHROMEDRIVER_EXE);
    e_driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(e_driver);
    eventListene = new WebEventListen();
    driver.register(eventListene);
```

}}

Comment: Could you share your tried code as well??

Comment: hey Saurabh, which Code? this is normal code for creating driver instance

Comment: share how are you initializing `WebDriver`..

Comment: Please update the question with the code that generates this error.

Comment: here is whole code of driver initialization

Comment: public Properties CONFIG = null;
    public WebDriver e_driver = null;
    public EventFiringWebDriver driver = null;
    public WebEventListen eventListene = null;

Comment: actually we are executing tests from bamboo on remote agent and that time I am getting this error..otherwise locally i dont get this kind of error.

Comment: restarting of server with tests solved the problem in my case =)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the docker host having actually run out of disk space. On docker toolbox (older or non-pro windows), and perhaps others too, this can be obscured because the docker host is actually a VM with a finite disk space.

To check you can run

```
docker-machine ssh
```

followed by

```
df -h
```

To re-create the docker host from scratch (which will loose all containers and images)

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```